# How to know difference in angle between two identical svg polygon?

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

I have some identical complex SVG polygons/paths with the only difference being their orientation ( and position...).
How can I compute the difference in angles between the two?

Comment: part of that depends on how you've changed their angles. Have you done a transform on one of them?

Comment: No, I didn't change the angles. The SVG paths are coming from an external source. I just know that some of the paths draw the same shape but with varying angles that I don't know

Comment: Do you have any examples of the paths in question?

Answer (score 1):

In general case you can calculate [image moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) for points forming a path.

With moments you get "centroids" - here arbitrary point characterizing figure position, and difference of centroids is shift between two similar paths.

Also you get "orientation" - and again this is arbitrary angle, but you need angle difference.